# Unit Testing function inside foreach loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am writing a unit test case, I have a scenario in which there is a function inside the loop. Can anyone tell me how I can unit test that?

```
function xyz(scope) {
 //how to test this loop
  angular.forEach(scope.$error, function (field) {
   angular.forEach(field, function (errorField) {
     errorField.$setTouched();
    });
   });
  }
```

Comment: You just call the method, xyz with a mocked up param-scope and finally check whether all the fields you've provided is touched.

Comment: It generated error 
errorField.$setTouched() $setTouched() is not a function.

Comment: Try and get the actual scope object and mock it properly. It looks like a formArray to me. If your mocked up object have all the methods and properties as of scope's, this error will not occur